# Como fazer uma DIV ajustar sua altura de acordo com a imagem background?

Tags: css

Como fazer uma DIV ajustar sua altura de acordo com a imagem background?

```
.guaraparivirtual-guiacomercial-banner {
position:relative;
width:900px;
height:auto;
float:left;
background-color:#dddddd;
background-image:url(img-guaraparivirtual/icone-whatsapp.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-origin:border-box;
background-size:auto;
}
```

Neste CSS acima é o que utilizo, mas não funciona. Preciso que a DIV detect automaticamente a altura da imagem background e se ajuste.

Aguardo ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não seja possível utilizando somente o CSS, porém você pode estar fazendo assim:

**HTML**

```
<div class="guaraparivirtual-guiacomercial-banner">
    <img src="img-guaraparivirtual/icone-whatsapp.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.guaraparivirtual-guiacomercial-banner {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
```

Colocando a imagem com HTML, e assim pondo-a dentro de uma DIV, da pra dizer que a DIV se ajustará automaticamente.

Se quiser da até pra aplicar alguns efeitos na DIV, para você fazer o teste e ver que realmente a div está se adaptando:

**CSS**

```
.guaraparivirtual-guiacomercial-banner {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    /* efeitos de exemplo para o teste */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
}
```